# getting line breaks in tinymce wysiwyg &nbsp;

Tags: wysiwyg

On a new drupal 7 installation, I'm trying to get line breaks to show up correctly when saved. I have wysiwyg and tinymce installed through using the panopoly distribution. When I try to do more space after a paragraph (by hitting enter twice), it will generate two empty paragraph tags, such as `<p></p><p></p>`. This however won't provide the needed space as they are empty. In an earlier (drupal 6) project, when I tested this behavior it would insert paragraphs with `&nbsp;` in them which correctly displayed the line breaks. For example: `<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>`

Is there any way to get this behavior back in Drupal 7?

I've played around with the wysiwyg settings, and text formats, but I can't find a combination of settings that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this has something to do with the "WYSIWYG filter" under text formats (admin/config/content/formats). Disabling this gave my non-breaking space back. You would probably want to adjust the configuration rather than just turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

The followin setup works in my Drupal 7 TinyMCE configuration:

1. Turn off the WYSYWIG filter on the admin/config/content/formats page.
2. Configure the 'Limit Allowed HTML tags' filter to allow for

   and 
    tags.

Note: Filters are configured at admin/config/content/formats/MY_FILTER_NAME

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

Drupal 6: Removed the CHARACTER REPLACEMENT "?" FOR NON-BREAKING-SPACE TAG in P tags from wysiwyg. The empty p tags were formerly placed to denote a change of line, however Drupal wysiwyg automatically adds a NON-BREAKING-SPACE TAG which thereby fail to display properly and thus be replaced with the CHARACTER REPLACEMENT "?"

Drupal 7: No nbsp tag but empty p tags

Working Solution:

```
$to_filter = array('bloc_1_delta', 'bloc_2_delta', 'bloc_3_delta', 'bloc_4_delta');
if (in_array($vars['block']->delta, $to_filter)) {
    $vars['block']->content = str_replace("<p></p>", "<br/>", mb_convert_encoding($vars['block']->content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
}
```